# zend_form -- how to get form values except for disables elements

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

i want to use zend_form to validate and filter the POST data,and some form fields are disabled element,
but when i use $form->isValid($post) filtering the data and use $form->getValues() to  get the filtered data, it returns all the elements value (including the disabled elements value which i don't want).

such as :

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="account_id" value="123456">

<input type="text"  name="name" value="">
<input type="text"  name="email" value="">

<input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="created_date" value="2011-06-12">
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="created_by" value="admin">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

so is there any way to get rid of the disables elements value ?
(because there are many fields and disabled elements ,so i don't want to trim them manually)

thanks!

Comment: how come your form can post disabled elements values? it is against specs.

Answer (score 4):

This is some sort of a hack. We get all elements and iterate through it. When we see an element is disabled we can skip.

```
$somearray = array();
$elements = $form->getElements();
foreach ($elements as $key => $element) {
    //echo $key;
    if( $element->disabled ) {
        continue;
    }
    $somearray[$key] = $element->getValue();
}
```

Hope this helps, or you can hack on it ;) .

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is not a bug, but an accepted workflow for validating forms. see this: http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-6909

it looks like the accepted solution/trick is to use

```
$form->isValidPartial($this->getRequest()->getPost())
```

instead of

```
$form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())
```

isValidPartial only tests the form fields that are present in the post. disabled elements should not end up posted.

Comment: He is trying `$form->getValues() to get the filtered data, it returns all the elements value (including the disabled elements value which i don't want)` . So `isValidPartial()` seems not the one.

Comment: I'm  pretty sure you are not correct. getValues() gets all of the values validated/filtered by the the isValid or isValidPartial function. isValidPartial only validates elements in the post. Disabled elements will never be part of the post. http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1 "In this example, the INPUT element is disabled. Therefore, it cannot receive user input nor will its value be submitted with the form."

Comment: Yes you are right, disabled elements will not come in post. That was something new for me. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: usually the disabled element won't post, but this can be changed by user  easily, so trust the post data is not safe.